# How to crawl only HTML in Nutch?

Tags: nutch

Is it possible to crawl/fetch only plain HTML pages via Nutch (i.e. no pictures, video, flash, excel, exe, pdf or word files)?

How to check `Content-Type` of the page and fetch only `text/html` pages via Nutch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `conf/regex-urlfilter.txt`:

Set files suffix for ignore:

```
-\.(jpg|gif|zip|ico)$
```